# Get Range of IpAddresses given in the form "9.1.0.0-10" in java

Tags: java

Need to get all Ips given in the form 9.1.0.0-10

output:

```
9.1.0.0
9.1.0.1
9.1.0.2
9.1.0.3
9.1.0.4
9.1.0.5
9.1.0.6
9.1.0.7
9.1.0.8
9.1.0.9
9.1.0.10
```

Is there any class that does this work or is there any way i can do it in better way

my java code:

```
String start = "9.1.0.0-10";

         String range[] = start.split("-");
         String[] startParts = range[0].split("(?<=\\.)(?!.*\\.)");
         int first = Integer.parseInt(startParts[1]);
         int last = Integer.parseInt(range[1]);

         for(int i=first;i<=last;i++)
         System.out.println(startParts[0] + i);
```

Comment: The syntax you've shown is non-standard. IP address ranges should really be expressed using CIDR. If they can't be expressed using CIDR, then they weren't really partitioned correctly.

Comment: Its just a notation to tell these Ipaddresess  are used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you split your address range by period first, then handle each token separately according to the presence of a dash. This way, you could as well handle ranges like 9.1.0-5.0-10.

I had to address this challenge some time ago, which led me to create an `InetAddressRange` class:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * Notation: n.n.n.n, where n can be:
 * - an integer such that 0 &lt;= n &lt;= 255;
 * - an interval m-n, where 0 &lt;= m &lt;= n &lt;= 255
 * - an asterisk (*), synonym for interval 0-255.
 * The address parts are stored as returned as 16-bits integers (short) in order to
 * avoid confusion that might come from the fact that integers between 128 and 255
 * are considered negative (-128 to -1) when handled as byte values.
 * Instances of this class are immutable.
 */
public class InetAddressRange {

  private static final Pattern P_DIGITS = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
  private static final Pattern P1 = Pattern.compile("([0-9\\*\\-\\[\\],]+)\\.([0-9\\*\\-\\[\\],]+)\\.([0-9\\*\\-\\[\\],]+)\\.([0-9\\*\\-\\[\\],]+)");
  private static final Pattern P2 = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\-(\\d+)");

  private final short[] min = new short[4];
  private final short[] max = new short[4];

  public InetAddressRange(String expr) {
    parse(expr);
  }

  private void parse(String expr) {
    Matcher m1 = P1.matcher(expr);
    if (!m1.matches()) {
      throw error(expr);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      String token = m1.group(i + 1);
      if (P_DIGITS.matcher(token).matches()) {
        // Integer between 0 and 255 (else only the last 8 bits are kept)
        min[i] = max[i] = (short) (Integer.parseInt(token) & 0xff);
      } else if (token.equals("*")) {
        // Asterisk = interval 0-255
        min[i] = 0;
        max[i] = 0xff;
      } else {
        // Interval a-b
        Matcher m2 = P2.matcher(token);
        if (m2.matches()) {
          min[i] = (short) (Integer.parseInt(m2.group(1)) & 0xff);
          max[i] = (short) (Integer.parseInt(m2.group(2)) & 0xff);
        } else {
          throw error(expr);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private static IllegalArgumentException error(String expr) {
    return new IllegalArgumentException("The expression " + expr + " isn't a valid IP address interval.");
  }

  public short getMin(int i) {
    return min[i];
  }

  public short getMax(int i) {
    return max[i];
  }

  public boolean isInRange(InetAddress adr) {
    byte[] parts = adr.getAddress();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      if (min[i] > (parts[i] & 0xff) || max[i] < (parts[i] & 0xff)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  public boolean isInRange(String adr) {
    String[] tokens = adr.split("\\.");
    if (tokens.length < 4) {
      return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      int part = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
      if (min[i] > part || max[i] < part) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  public List<String> getAddresses() {
    List<String> addrs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (short a = min[0]; a <= max[0]; a++) {
      for (short b = min[1]; b <= max[1]; b++) {
        for (short c = min[2]; c <= max[2]; c++) {
          for (short d = min[3]; d <= max[3]; d++) {
            String addr = String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d", a, b, c, d);
            addrs.add(addr);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return addrs;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    InetAddressRange range = new InetAddressRange("9.1.0.0-10");
    range.getAddresses().forEach(System.out::println);
  }

}
```

The `getAddresses()` method will generate the addresses you need (see the `main()` method for an example).

Cheers,

Jeff

Comment: My code handles intervals in any part of an IPv4 address, including multiple intervals.